# Spring websocket set handshake handler/interceptor

Tags: spring-websocket

I try to set `handshake handler` through xml config:

```
<bean id="customHandler" class="app.wsock.CustomHandler"/>

<websocket:message-broker>
  <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/foo">
    <websocket:handshake-handler ref="customHandler"/>
    <websocket:sockjs/>
  </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
  <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic,/queue" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

but on connect also using DefaultHandshakeHandler. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug (see [SPR-11568](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11568)).
You'll need to update your app to Spring Framework 4.0.3.