# Spring Java config for custom websocket handshake on stomp endpoint

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-java-config, spring-websocket

I would like to have the equivalent of this XML configuration (taken [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447794/spring-websocket-set-handshake-handler-interceptor/)), but using Java config:

```
<bean id="customHandler" class="app.wsock.CustomHandler"/>

<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
  <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/foo">
    <websocket:handshake-handler ref="customHandler"/>
  </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
  <websocket:simpl-broker prefix="/topic,/queue" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

My goal is to build a class that limits the connection to my STOMP endpoint (i.e.: to his websocket) based on some criteria.

I don't want to use XML to configure my endpoint, how do I convert that snippet to Java Config?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public HandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {
        return new app.wsock.CustomHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/foo").setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry configurer) {
        configurer.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue");
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to override various methods like isValidOrigin(), handleInvalidConnectHeader(), determineUser() but none of them gets called.

I suppose the class do not even get instantiated.

(I'm using Spring Boot if this may help)

Comment: ??? It is a different question and it is related to wrong way to build a custom `HandshakeHandler`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what do you mean, as stated in the question "My goal is to build a class that limits the connection to my STOMP endpoint (i.e.: to his websocket) based on some criteria.", but the handshake built this way is not being used for the handshaking, so it's not useful, it's just a bean uncorrelated with the websocket

Comment: No, your question was about `Java config equivalent`. If you have a trouble with some custom code, you should start a new question. Please, be more specific and don't share several questions in one topic.

Comment: What I mean is that the Java config is *not* equivalent to the XML I reported in my question: with the XML configuration the handshakeHandler gets correctly called, while in the java configuration you provide it's not used at all, so unsuitable for the work it has to do.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what's going on in your case. Here is a working sample from Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket/client/StompIntegrationTests.java#L348

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60590/discussion-between-alessandro-polverini-and-artem-bilan).